# Sort JSON document by values embedded in an array of objects

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a document in the below format. The goal is to group the document by student name and sort it by rank in the ascending order. Once that is done, iterate through the rank(within a student) and if each subsequent rank is greater than the previous one, the version field needs to be incremented. As part of a pipeline, student_name will be passed to me so matching by student name should be good instead of grouping.

NOTE: Tried it with python and works to some extent. A python solution would also be great!

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d389c7907bf860f5cd11220"),
        "class" : "I",
        "students" : [
            {
                "student_name" : "AAA",
                "Version" : 2,
                "scores" : [
                    {
                        "value" : "50",
                        "rank" : 2
                    },
                    {
                        "value" : "70",
                        "rank" : 1
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "student_name" : "BBB",
                "Version" : 5,
                "scores" : [
                    {
                        "value" : 80,
                        "rank" : 2
                    },
                    {
                        "value" : 100,
                        "rank" : 1
                    },
                    {
                        "value" : 100,
                        "rank" : 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

I tried this piece of code to sort

```
    def version(student_name):
        db.column.aggregate(
            [
           {"$unwind": "$students"},
           {"$unwind": "$students.scores"},
           {"$sort" : {"students.scores.rank" : 1}},
           {"$group" : {"students.student_name}
            ]
       )

for i in range(0,(len(students.scores)-1)):
    if students.scores[i].rank < students.scores[i+1].rank:
       tag.update_many(
           {"$inc" : {"students.Version":1}}
       )
```

The expected output for student AAA should be

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d389c7907bf860f5cd11220"),
        "class" : "I",
        "students" : [
            {
                "student_name" : "AAA",
                "Version" : 3, #version incremented
                "scores" : [
                    {
                        "value" : "70",
                        "rank" : 1
                    },
                    {
                        "value" : "50",
                        "rank" : 2
                    }
                ]
            }
```

Comment: can you add a sample document of your expected output

Comment: I have added expected output and explained how the version is incremented

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort the document.

```
 pipeline = [
            {"$unwind": "$properties"},
            {"$unwind": "$properties.values"},
            {"$sort" : {"$properties.values.rank" : -1}},
            {"$group": {"_id" : "$properties.property_name", "values" : {"$push" : "$properties.values"}}}
        ]

import pprint
pprint.pprint(list(db.column.aggregate(pipeline)))
```